# What do you think about cascading deletions on mysql tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, cascade

This question is in the title !

The database i'm using to store datas from my (production) website contains a lot of `ON DELETE CASCADE`.

I just would know if it's a good thing or if it's a better way to manually code all deletions.

On one hand, it's not very explicit : deletions are made by magic and on a other hand, it make development easier : I don't have to keep the entire schema of my database in my mind.

Comment: Personally I wouldn't trust MySQL to do it.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: if you have such distrust then perhaps you should use a RDBMS in which you feel you can have more trust. (Maybe that is the point you were making, I do not know.) If you avoid using the basic relational database features of yor RDBMS then you are probably making more work for yourself than necessary.

Comment: @Hammerite Not using MySQL was the point.

Comment: Well, if you are using ON DELETE triggers then it is true it is wiser not to trust MySQL to perform cascading deletes on those tables. In any other case I am not aware of a reason to be so suspicious.

Answer (score 1):

I think maintaining referential integrity is a good thing to be doing. The last thing you'd want is orphaned rows in your database.

See the MySQL documentation on things to consider when not using referential integrity:

> MySQL gives database developers the choice of which approach to use. If you don't need foreign keys and want to avoid the overhead associated with enforcing referential integrity, you can choose another storage engine instead, such as MyISAM. (For example, the MyISAM storage engine offers very fast performance for applications that perform only INSERT and SELECT operations. In this case, the table has no holes in the middle and the inserts can be performed concurrently with retrievals. See Section 8.10.3, “Concurrent Inserts”.)
>
> If you choose not to take advantage of referential integrity checks, keep the following considerations in mind:
>
> In the absence of server-side foreign key relationship checking, the application itself must handle relationship issues. For example, it must take care to insert rows into tables in the proper order, and to avoid creating orphaned child records. It must also be able to recover from errors that occur in the middle of multiple-record insert operations.
>
> If ON DELETE is the only referential integrity capability an application needs, you can achieve a similar effect as of MySQL Server 4.0 by using multiple-table DELETE statements to delete rows from many tables with a single statement. See Section 13.2.2, “DELETE Syntax”.
>
> A workaround for the lack of ON DELETE is to add the appropriate DELETE statements to your application when you delete records from a table that has a foreign key. In practice, this is often as quick as using foreign keys and is more portable.
>
> Be aware that the use of foreign keys can sometimes lead to problems:
>
> Foreign key support addresses many referential integrity issues, but it is still necessary to design key relationships carefully to avoid circular rules or incorrect combinations of cascading deletes.
>
> It is not uncommon for a DBA to create a topology of relationships that makes it difficult to restore individual tables from a backup. (MySQL alleviates this difficulty by enabling you to temporarily disable foreign key checks when reloading a table that depends on other tables. See Section 14.3.5.4, “FOREIGN KEY Constraints”. As of MySQL 4.1.1, mysqldump generates dump files that take advantage of this capability automatically when they are reloaded.)

Source: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/ansi-diff-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 0):

Cascading deletes are a great tool for you to use provided you make sure only to use them where it makes perfect sense to do so.

The main situation in which you would opt for using a cascading delete is when you have a table that models entities that are "owned" by one (and only one) row in another table. For example, if you have a table that models people and a table that models phone numbers. Here your phone numbers table would have a foreign key to your people table. Now if you decide you no longer want your application to keep track of someone - say "Douglas" - it makes perfect sense that you don't want to keep track of Douglas's phone numbers any more, either. There is no sense in having a phone number floating around in your database and not know whose it is.

But at the same time, when you want to delete a person from the "people" table, you don't want to first have to laboriously check whether you have any phone numbers for that person and delete them. Why do that when you can encode into the database structure the rule that when a person is deleted, their phone numbers can all go as well? That is what a cascading delete will do for you. Just make sure you know what cascading deletes you have, and that they all make sense.

NB. If you use triggers, you need to be more careful. MySQL doesn't fire triggers on cascading deletes.